# Ant Media Server WebRTC connection in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc, ant-media-server-sdk

I've been following this tutorial : https://antmedia.io/webrtc-streaming-in-unity/ in order to try and receive a WebRTC stream into unity.

I've downloaded the https://github.com/ant-media/WebRTC-Unity-SDK WebRTC unity SDK.

I created a Ant Server on Linode and broadcast into it using OBS.

The unity sample does not look like the one in the tutorial/

I opened the AMSStreaming scene In Unity, and modified the url in the AMSStreaming script to point to my server : "ws://my_server_ip:5080/WebRTCApp/websocket"

and provided the WebRTCClient with the correct stream id and url.

I left the stun server to the default stun server address : stun:stun.l.google.com:19302

Running the sample, I set the comboBox to "Play" and click "Start".

The connection works fine and

```
    else if(mode == MODE_PLAY) {
        webRTClient.Play();
```

gets executed.

However nothing else happens, no RTCTrackEvent are received.

I have also placed a breakpoint in the CreatePeerConnection() Method :

```
    localPC.OnIceConnectionChange = state => { 
        switch (state)
        {
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Connected:
                //PeerConnected();
                //break;
            case RTCIceConnectionState.New:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Checking:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Closed:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Completed:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Disconnected:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Failed:
            case RTCIceConnectionState.Max:
                Debug.Log("IceConnectionState: "+state);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(state), state, null);
        };
    };
```

That never gets hit, so the ICEConnectionChange never changes.

Could that be the problem ?

How can I move forward debugging this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Unity SDK told in the document you shared is obsolute and has a different repository than you shaerd.

The repository you shared is new Unity SDK, you can download and use it without following the document you sent.

For the issue you sent, I have just tried to publish an RTMP stream and I could play with Unity.

Can you try with the latest [master branch](https://github.com/ant-media/WebRTC-Unity-SDK).